# Fetching NPM global packages

Tags: node.js, npm, child-process

Trying to build a Node CLI to do some backup tasks including fetching NPM packages. I ended up writing this function:

```js
function getNPNGlobalPackages(cb) {
    require('child_process').exec(
        'npm list -g --json',
        function (err, res, err) {
            if (err) return cb(err);
            const result = JSON.parse(res);
            const packages = result.dependencies;
            console.log(packages);
        }
    );
}
```

The issue with this result is I can't edit output and I feel there could be better approach to do it.

Output:

```
{
  '@ionic/cli': { version: '6.18.0' },
  '@nestjs/cli': { version: '8.1.5' },
  '@vue/cli-init': { version: '4.5.13' },
  '@vue/cli': { version: '4.5.13' },
  ...
}
```

When I try to get `packages[0]` I get `undefined`. What am I doing wrong ?

My goal is to end up having something like `packagename@version`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

packages is an object. So, if you want to get a value you have to get it by key (Here you are trying to get from index).

For your end goal try this

```
const res = Object.keys(packages).map(pkg => `${pkg}@${packages[pkg]['version']}`);
```